# Need Ticker For SeekBar to be clickable more than once

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, seekbar

I have a seekBar, and want to have "ticker" buttons for easy increments of 1. As of now, my text updates only once. However, if my seekBar is changed, I am able to tick + 1 one more time.Let me know if you want to see more code..everything else works fine.

```
 ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int addOne = 1;
            progress = seekBar.getProgress(); 
            progress = progress + addOne;
            if(progress  < 18)
                textView1.setText(":  "+ 18);
            textView1.setText(":  " + progress);
         ib2.setClickable(true);

        }
    });     
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
      {

            @Override
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,int progresValue, boolean fromUser) 
          {
                progresValue = 18;
            progress = progresValue;

            if(progress < 18)
            {
                 progress = 18;
                 textView1.setText(":  "+ progress);
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
          {
                textView1.setText(":   ");
                progress= seekBar.getProgress();
                textView1.setText(":  " + progress);
          }

          @Override
          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
          {
              if(seekBar.getProgress() < 18)
              {
                  progress = 18;
                 textView1.setText(":  " + progress );

              }
              else
              {

              textView1.setText(":  " + seekBar.getProgress());
              }
          }
      });
```

Comment: Why do you set the `progresValue` to 18 at the beginning of your `onProgressChanged` method?

Comment: I'm trying to set a minimum value. I don't want the value to go below 18. This code was copy & pasted at a point where i was randomly guessing and checking after a while, so some of might make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you forgot to set the progress of the `SeekBar` after incrementing it. You have to add:

```
seekBar.setProgress(progress);
```

at the end of your `onClick` method.

---

BTW, your code can be simplified a lot, the following code does exactly the same as yours but in a shorter way:

```
ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() + 1);
    }
});     

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
        if(progresValue < 18) {
            textView1.setText(":  "+ 18);
        } else {
            textView1.setText(":  "+ progresValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        textView1.setText(":  " + seekBar.getProgress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a simplified version of your code. It should be easier to understand and use. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks again! Anyway to start the seek bar as showing at 18? (on the actual bar?)

Comment: You **can't** set the minimum value of your `SeekBar` which always starts at 0. But you can add 18 every time you get or set its progress. This offset will make your `SeekBar` start at 18. Just keep in mind that this will also increase your max value by 18. If needed, you can set the maximum value either in the XML definition or programmatically.